# uploading an image with node js, next js and multer is not working

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, next.js, multer

I've been struggling with this for several days now.
I'm creating an application where users can create accounts and eventually upload profile pics, and I'm trying to use multer for uploading the images through an input, in a form element that has several fields for user data. However, the image file won't be sent to the "uploads" file, nor the file is getting created.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. (I'm not including most of the code in this post to preventing it from getting too long but please let me know if you need anything else)

I've created this "uploadsController" for setting multer:

```
import multer from 'multer';

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false
  }
}


    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function (req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, 'uploads')
          },
        filename: function (req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, `${Date.now()}-${file.originalname}`);
        },
      });
      
      const upload = multer({ storage: storage });

      


export { upload };
```

Then I have this component called PerfilFormData, that contains the form with the input:

```
  const handleImageChange = (e) => {
        const file = e.target.files[0];
        if (file) {
            const reader = new FileReader()
            reader.readAsDataURL(file)
            reader.onload = function load() {
                setImagen(reader.result);
            }
            setArchivoImagen(file)
        } else {
            console.log('No es una imagen')
        }
    };

   const handleSubmit = async e => {
        e.preventDefault()

 try {
    const { data } = await clienteAxios.put(`/usuarios/perfil/${auth._id}`, datosActualizados);
} catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
   }

   return (
<>
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" onSubmit={handleSubmit}> 
 <input
name="profileImage"
className='focus:outline-none focus:border-none'
type="file"
accept="image/*"
id="upload-input"
style={{ display: 'none' }}
ref={inputRef}
onChange={handleImageChange}
/>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
 </form>
</>
)
```

And finally, I've set this routes file called "usuarioRoutes":

```
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

import { 
    upload
} from '../controllers/uploadsController.js';

router.put('/perfil/:id', editarPerfil, upload.single('profileImage'));

export default router;
```

I need the image uploaded to the input in the form to be sent to the folder 'uploads' in the project, through the form that has been set in the frontend of the page via multer.

Comment: Please check out this tutorial. [Tutorial](https://www.section.io/engineering-education/uploading-files-using-multer-nodejs/)